# Структура данных для потокобезопасного графа (не бинарный)

Tags: java, алгоритм, многопоточность, графы, структуры-данных

Недавно получил на интервью любопытную задачу, сам с ней не справился, но очень интересно как ее можно было решить.

**Задача**

> Построить структуру данных для графа.
>
> Структура должна поддерживать 2 типа графов - направленных и ненаправленных.
>
> Вершины должны быть параметризованы.
>
> С 3-мя операциями:
>
> `addVertex` - добавляет вершину на граф.
> `addEdge` - добавляет ребро на граф.
> `getPath` - возвращает список ребер между 2 вершинами (путь не обязательно должен быть оптимальным).

Моя попытка в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014705/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0#1014705)

Но метод `getPath` мне в нем реализовать не удалось, возможно из за изначально неверно выбранной структуры данных, а может быть и нет.

В любом случае буду весьма признателен любому работающему варианту.

Comment: да самый простой вариант на базе `ConcurrentLinkedQueue< ConcurrentLinkedQueue<E> >` какой-нибудь.

Comment: @pavel причем тут очереди? 0_о это как?

Comment: В Java сейчас ведь уже вроде бы добавили нормальные [мьютексы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5291062/7286264). Вот и лочьте ресурсы по ним

Comment: @avp да потокобезопасность не главное главное как путь найти. Уберу лучше это требование это я и сам сделаю. Помогите с getPath он не получается

Comment: Как найти путь? А что-нибудь о графах Вы уже прочитали? Там обязательно упоминаются **обходы** графов.

Comment: @MBo да разумеется в принципе мне не хватает только метода getPath остальное сделал, но с ним что-то не как не выходит https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014705/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B0#1014705