# Получить список ребер между двумя вершинами графа

Tags: java, алгоритм, графы, структуры-данных

Нужно реализовать метод `getPath` так чтобы он возвращал список ребер, путь не обязательно должен быть оптимальным, но должно учитываться `isDirected` то есть направленный ли граф. Не уверен что объект `Edge`(ребро) должен быть таким.

Текущая реализация `getPath` и метода `collect` работает только если граф в форме связанного списка. В остальных случаях не работает.

Конструктивная критика по поводу базовой структуры данных

`Map<Vertex<T>, List<Edge<T>>>`

очень приветствуется, не уверен что это хороший вариант.

```
public class Graph<T> {

    private boolean isDirected = false;

    private Map<Vertex<T>, List<Edge<T>>> graph = new HashMap<>();

    public Graph() {
    }

    public Graph(boolean isDirected) {
        this.isDirected = isDirected;
    }

    public void addEdge(T first, T second) {
        final Vertex<T> master = new Vertex<>(first);
        final Vertex<T> slave = new Vertex<>(second);

        final Set<Vertex<T>> vertices = graph.keySet();
        if (!vertices.contains(master) || !vertices.contains(slave)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        graph.get(master).add(new Edge<>(master, slave));

        if (!isDirected) {
            graph.get(slave).add(new Edge<>(slave, master));
        }
    }

    public void addVertex(T value) {
        final List<Edge<T>> result = graph.putIfAbsent(new Vertex<>(value), new ArrayList<>());
        if (result != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public Set<Edge<T>> getPath(T from, T to) {
        final Set<Edge<T>> visitedEdges = new HashSet<>();
        if (from.equals(to)) {
            return visitedEdges;
        }

        if (!isDirected) throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported operation (Only directed graph)");

        return collect(new Vertex<>(from), new Vertex<>(to), new HashSet<>());
    }

    private Set<Edge<T>> collect(Vertex<T> previous, Vertex<T> target, Set<Edge<T>> visited) {
        Vertex<T> current = null;
        for (Edge<T> edge : graph.get(previous)) {
            current = edge.getNext();
            visited.add(edge);
            if (current.equals(target)) {
                return visited;
            }
        }

        return isNull(current) ? visited : collect(current, target, visited);
    }
}
```

Вершина:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Vertex<T> {
    private T value;
}
```

Ребро:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Edge<T> {
    private Vertex<T> back;
    private Vertex<T> next;
}
```

Comment: А почему бы не использовать общеизвестные алгоритмы поиска пути, например, поиск в ширину или алгоритм Дейкстры?

Comment: @Agneth можно попробовать.